# Is User creation without email possible in ABP?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate v1.0.

Recently, we had a client requesting for User creation without providing email. In my evaluation, it seems like `EmailAddress` is compulsory in the architecture for `AbpUser`.

So, to proceed with this, I need to know the possibility of User creation without email.

Thanks and Regards,
George Vargheese
ABP Forum Username: George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in this topic: [Unique email for user by tenant](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=26294)

> In general, it *is* not possible due to a limitation (feature) of the `Required` attribute.
>
> A workaround for your design decision is to generate a placeholder,
>   e.g. 0000-0000-0000-0000@example.com (where 0000-0000-0000-0000 is a `NewGuid`).